# copy NSData to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>

Tags: c, swift, swift2, unsafe-pointers, secure-transport

Hi there stackoverflowers. I'm implementing a wrapper for Secure Transport and I'm stuck on some of the C -> Swift syntax.

```
func sslReadCallback(connection: SSLConnectionRef,
    data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
    var dataLength: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> OSStatus
{
    //let bytesRequested = dataLength.memory
    let transportWrapper:SecureTransportWrapper = UnsafePointer(connection).memory
    let bytesRead:NSData = transportWrapper.readFromConnectionFunc(transportWrapper.connection)
    
    dataLength = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)
    dataLength.initialize(bytesRead.length)
    
    if (bytesRead.length == 0)
    {
        return OSStatus(errSSLClosedGraceful)
    }
    else
    {
        data.alloc(sizeof(bytesRead.length)) //<----compile error here
        return noErr
    }
}
```

I've marked the location of the compile error. I don't blame it for erring, I was kind of guessing here :P. I'm trying to copy the the NSData to the data:UnsafeMutablePointer. How do I do that?

Compile error:

> /Users/*/SecureTransportWrapper.swift:108:9: Static member 'alloc' cannot be used on instance of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<()>')

Thanks a ton!

================

Update: here is the api doc for what the sslReadCallback is supposed to do:

> connection: A connection reference.
>
> data: On return, your callback should overwrite the memory at this location with the data read from the connection.
>
> dataLength: On input, a pointer to an integer
> representing the length of the data in bytes. On return, your callback
> should overwrite that integer with the number of bytes actually
> transferred.

Excerpt from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SSLReadFunc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, lets go through your code:

```
dataLength = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)
dataLength.initialize(bytesRead.length)
```

`dataLength` is a pointer you get passed in, it is where the caller of the function both gives you the size of the buffer *and* wants you to put the number of bytes you read. You don't need to alloc this, it is already allocated.

(Irrelevant for this example but: Also in alloc(N) and initialize(N) the N should be the same (it is the amount of memory being allocated, and then initialized))

I think what you want (Swift 3 uses `pointee` instead of `memory`) is this:

```
dataLength.memory = bytesRead.length
```

The C API says that you also get the size of the `data` buffer from this variable. `data` will be pre-allocated for this size.

Make sure the data you read fits (`bytesRead.length <= dataLength.memory`), then just do a

```
memcpy(data, bytesRead.bytes, bytesRead.length)
```

That's all.

Comment: Nope, as long as your answers match the docs! Thanks a lot - I'll mark yours as correct.